# How can I calculate Jaccard index between a set of different keywords

Tags: r, similarity

Here is an example of the data I am dealing with :

```
AuthorId    abstract
2163160142  "We propose a new version of HLLEM approximate Riemann solver where loca..."
2218860995  "PLM is today a reality for mechanical SMEs. Some companies..."
2186116765  "Classic surgical interruption of patent ductus arteriosus was partially..."
2183638412  "Nanotechnology is currently undergoing rapid development partly due to the..."
2797413770  "The first aim of this article is to understand how the preschool teacher’s..."
2185043195  "In the lobster Homarus, the 2 identified PS neurons have a strong suppressive..."
2285431655  "Introduction: La polymedication des personnes âgees est un probleme sanitaire..."
2228363342  "A ring opening polymerization process allowing the fast and controlled..."
```

In the data, each abstract belongs to a specific author and the same author can have multiple abstracts. So the goal is to calculate the Jaccard index of each combination of abstracts that an author has.
Let **Wa** be the set of unique words of abstract a. The Jaccard index between two abstracts a and b is defined as:        **Jaccardab = |Wa ∩Wb|/|Wa ∪Wb|**

I tried this :

```
dist <- unlist(lapply(combn(list, 2, simplify = FALSE), function(x) {
  length(intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]))/length(union(x[[1]], x[[2]])) }))
```

But I don't know how to apply it to each specific author and the abstracts related to them.
I need to also calculate the specialization of each author by this formula :
Using the Jaccard measure, the specialization measure for scientist i writes:
Specialization = 1 /ni ×(ni −1)*sum(Jaccard-ab)

which is simply the average Jaccard measure between all pairs of publications of scientist i. Of course, the higher this value, the
more specialized the scientist is.

Answer (score 1):

If your data set is named `x`, maybe the following does what you are looking for.

```
library(stringdist)

by(x, x$AuthorId, \(y)
   stringdistmatrix(y$abstract, method = 'jaccard')
)
```

Comment: I want the index of each combination of a certain number of abstracts belonging to an author in another column. And what  \(y) does ? Thank you